# How should I store EEG data in FHIR to store my data as electronic health record(EHR)?

Tags: dstu2-fhir, hl7-fhir

I have EEG data sets which are either Matlab or EDF format. I want to store them as FHIR records.
And also are  there any sample mental health records available in FHIR format?

Answer (score 2):

Matlab or EDF data would be stored as Binary.  If you want to capture metadata about it (e.g. what patient it's for, when it was created, etc.), you can use Media.

I'd suggest raising the question about mental health records on http://chat.fhir.org.  I'm not aware of any as part of the specification.

Comment: Are there any sample mental health records available for FHIR?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  Again, I'd recomment querying on chat.fhir.org - you'll find a wider audience there.